# DataGridView not updating in function call

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView present in my mainForm, which is visible to the user. I have a Global Variable that is a list of objects that contain the data I wish to bind to the DataGridView. The problem is that my function updateGridView(), when called, does not update the DataGridView. I have done some testing and I figured out that a button placed on the form, when added the same code, does update the DataGridView. How is this so? Is this some access issue that I've been overlooking?

Global Variable Definition:

```
public static class GlobalVars
{
    public static List<Models.Session> sessionList = new List<Models.Session>();
}
```

Session Definition:

```
// Defined under the 'Models' namespace
public class Session
{
    // Session structure
    public int traineeID = 0;
    public Trainee traineeData = null;
    public DateTime startTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    public DateTime endTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    public double sessionTime = 0;
    public bool isFinished = false;
}
```

All code below is found within the mainForm.cs file:

updateGridView() function:

```
public void updateGridView()
{
    residencyDataView.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (Models.Session session in GlobalVars.sessionList)
    {
        // Iterate and add to GridView
        string traineeName;
        string loginTime;
        string logoutTime;
        string totalTime;

        if (session.traineeData.Nickname == "")
            traineeName = session.traineeData.FirstName;
        else
            traineeName = session.traineeData.Nickname;

        loginTime = session.startTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

        if(session.isFinished)
        {
            logoutTime = session.endTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
            totalTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(session.sessionTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
        else
        {
            logoutTime = "---";
            totalTime = "Still Logged In";
        }
        // MessageBox just to show data contents for testing
        MessageBox.Show(traineeName + "\n" + loginTime + "\n" + logoutTime + "\n" + totalTime);
        residencyDataView.Rows.Add(traineeName, loginTime, logoutTime, totalTime);
    }
}
```

The test button that works definition:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    residencyDataView.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (Models.Session session in GlobalVars.sessionList)
    {
        // Iterate and add to GridView
        string traineeName;
        string loginTime;
        string logoutTime;
        string totalTime;

        if (session.traineeData.Nickname == "")
            traineeName = session.traineeData.FirstName;
        else
            traineeName = session.traineeData.Nickname;

        loginTime = session.startTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

        if (session.isFinished)
        {
            logoutTime = session.endTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
            totalTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(session.sessionTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        }
        else
        {
            logoutTime = "---";
            totalTime = "Still Logged In";
        }


        residencyDataView.Rows.Add(traineeName, loginTime, logoutTime, totalTime);

    }
}
```

Both the updateGridView() and button are defined under:

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
```

#### What I've Tried:

- Using a test button (as defined above)
- Using a DataTable to bind data
- Used a MessageBox (as seen in updateGridView()) to check data contents

I've been completely dumbfounded and was trying to search for a solution since yesterday. Any help would be gladly appreciated, thanks!

#### EDIT (06/09/2020 - 5:33 PM PST):

- The updateGridView() function's caller makes changes to the global variable before the function is called.
- The residencyGridView is read-only for the application's user.
- This is how the updateGridView() function is called:

```
// Update the DataGridView
mainForm Form = new mainForm();
Form.updateGridView();
```

- I tried adding the following function in the same class within the "mainForm.cs" file (the form where the DataGridView is):

```
private void test() 
{
    residencyDataView.Rows.Add("Test", "Test", "Test", "Test");
}
```

and manually called the function by having a button call it. The GridView still does not update. I also tried changing the function's protection level to public.

Having the button run the `residencyDataView.Rows.Add("Test", "Test", "Test", "Test");` statement by itself does update the GridView, as I have stated earlier.

### UPDATE:

Somehow if I call the function within the same class, it works:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateGridView();
}
```

Comment: Where in the code you are calling `updateGridView()`?

Comment: It is difficult to follow what you are asking. The posted code appears to be clearing the grids rows, then re-adding them from the global variable `sessionList`… When you state that _”my function updateGridView(), when called, does not update the DataGridView”_ ? What are you expecting it to do? If the global variable `sessionList` is never changed (which in the posted code I do not see that it is), then what “update” are you expecting?

Comment: If the user “changes” something in the grid “after” the code adds the rows, then these changes are NOT going to be reflected back in the `sessionList` variable because the code adds the rows “manually” without using a data source. From _“What I’ve Tried”_ section, … I do not see where you tried to use the `sessionList` variable as a `DataSource` to the grid. `residencyDataView.DataSource = sessionList;`

Comment: Given the incomplete “Session” Class, a `List<Models.Session>` should work as a `DataSource` to the grid. Adding the rows manually seems like a waste of effort when `residencyDataView.DataSource = sessionList` should do the same thing AND this would also “update” the list when the user makes changes in the grid. Again, it is unclear what the code is trying to update.

Comment: @JohnG, the caller of updateGridView() either adds a new member to the sessionList object-list or makes changes to its existing members then calls the function afterwards. The DataGridView is locked from editing and is read only for the user. The code simply clears the grid then repopulates it with all the data from sessionList. I have tried the DataTable, but have not shown it here. Will make an edit here after trying it out once again to show how I implemented it (still didn't work though). I will try your suggestion of using the list as a direct DataSource.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, the caller of the updateGridView() function lies under a 'sub' namespace. The function is being called properly, so I know that it at least isn't an issue.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I've tried calling the function from the same form using a button. For some reason, it works as I would like to, but only when manually hitting the button. Is it the case that calling updateGridView() from the handler function that it's originally being called from plays a part on how the GridView works? Am I overlooking any access rights or concepts?

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean. I do not see anywhere in the code where the code is adding “anything” to the `sessionList`…. Where is this code? As I stated previously, adding the rows to the GRID which there IS code for, however, this is NOT going to add the data to the `sessionList`. Show the code where items are added to the `sessionList`.

Comment: @JohnG, I am not trying to add data to sessionList using the code above. I have a separate function that does it before updateGridView() is called.
User Input -> SessionList update -> updateGridView().

Comment: You are over complicating things. Show where you add items to the `sessionList`. The `UpdateGridView` method is completely unnecessary if you “bind” the `List<Models.Session>` … `sessionList` to the grid… `residencyDataView.DataSource = sessionList`. Again, without seeing the code that adds the items to the variable `sessionsList`, we must assume this is done correctly. I still do not understand “why” you keep looping through this list and add the rows “manually” to the grid…. This is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a complete example of what I am describing. In the future, when posting code, you should add the “complete” code. Parts that are missing like the `Trainee` class or having to “add” new items to the `sessionList` will only require more work for those trying to help you. Most will move on to other questions if they have to add a bunch of code “guessing” what you are doing.

With that said, below is a bare bone `Models` class. It should be noted that if you want to use the `Session` class in a `List<Model.Session>` and use that as a `DataSource` to the grid… that the `Trainee` `traineeData` will NOT display in the grid since it is a different class. However, all you need to do is “add” these properties to the `Session` class as done below and they should then be shown in the grid.

When the form loads, the global list `sessionList` is populated with some random `Session` data and then this `sessionList` is used as a `DataSource` to the grid. Then, there is a button that “adds” a new `Session` item to the `sessionList`. After the item is “added” to the list, the grid is refreshed to show the added `Session`. The refresh is simply setting the grids `DataSource` to `null` then again to the `sessionList.` The newly added item should now be displayed in the grid.

Bear in mind, that when you set the grids `DataSource` to some collection…. Then you CAN NOT programmatically ADD rows to the GRID. If you want to add rows to the grid… then you need to add those rows to the `DataSource` (`sessionList`) … not the grid.

Below is a complete `Models` Class…

```
public class Models {

  public class Session {
    public int traineeID { get; set; }
    public Trainee traineeData;
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
    public double sessionTime { get; set; }
    public bool isFinished { get; set; }

    public Session(int traineeID, Trainee traineeData, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, double sessionTime, bool isFinished) {
      this.traineeID = traineeID;
      this.traineeData = traineeData;
      this.startTime = startTime;
      this.endTime = endTime;
      this.sessionTime = sessionTime;
      this.isFinished = isFinished;
    }
    public Session() {
      traineeID = 0;
      traineeData = null;
      startTime = DateTime.MinValue;
      endTime = DateTime.MinValue;
      sessionTime = 0;
      isFinished = false;
    }

    public string TraineeFirstName {
      get {
        return traineeData.FirstName;
      }
    }
    public string TraineeNickName {
      get {
        return traineeData.Nickname;
      }
    }
  }

  public class Trainee {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
  }

}
```

Next the code that fills a list of random `Session` data into a `List<Model.Session>` `sessionLilst`. Then this list is used as a data source to the grid. Lastly a button to simulate adding new `Session` objects to the list and updating the grid to show the newly added `Session` objects.

```
public List<Models.Session> sessionList;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  sessionList = GetSessionData();
  residencyDataView.DataSource = sessionList;
}

private List<Models.Session> GetSessionData() {
  List<Models.Session> list = new List<Models.Session>();
  Models.Trainee trainee;
  Models.Session session;
  Random rand = new Random();
  int currand;
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    currand = rand.Next(1, 25);
    trainee = new Models.Trainee { FirstName = "FN_" + currand, Nickname = "Nick: " + currand };
    session = new Models.Session(currand, trainee, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(8), 8.00, true);
    list.Add(session);
  }
  return list;
}

private void btn_AddNewData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Models.Trainee trainee = new Models.Trainee { FirstName = "John", Nickname = "Nick" };
  Models.Session newSession = new Models.Session {
    traineeID = 22,
    traineeData = trainee,
    isFinished = false,
    startTime = DateTime.Now,
    endTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8),
    sessionTime = 8.00
  };
  sessionList.Add(newSession);
  residencyDataView.DataSource = null;
  residencyDataView.DataSource = sessionList;
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, thanks! This gave me good insights on the proper implementation of a model class. What solved it though, after revising it to use the list as a DataSource is how you refreshed the GridView by setting the DataSource to null then resetting it back to the list. And as advised, I've also transferred the globals list to the same class in the mainForm. Thanks for your help! Great insight. Will do my best to improve on my future questions (this is my first).